# pgf error maths

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pgfplotstable

help me please:

I don't understand why pgf show me this error, for all my dates:

```
Package PGF Math Error: Could not parse input '14.099117,3.068e+6,' as a floating point number, sorry. The unreadable part was near ',3.068e+6,'.. \addplot[color=black] file{dicloro.txt};
```

this is my archive:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable, pgf}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colorbrewer}
\usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}
\selectcolormodel{cmyk}
\usepackage{mathtools,amsmath,amsthm}
\usetikzlibrary{spy}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\pgfplotsset{/pgf/number format/use comma,compat=newest}

%opening
\title{PGF plots}
\author{Juliana Pérez}

\begin{document}
    
\maketitle  
    

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[xlabel=p1, ylabel=p1t, tick style={draw=none}]
        
    \addplot[color=black] file{dicloro.txt};
        
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}   

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think `pgfplots` assumes that columns in data files are separated by a space by default, and you seem to have comma separated columns. Try using

```
\addplot[color=black] table[col sep=comma]{dicloro.txt};
```

instead of `\addplot[color=black] file{dicloro.txt};`.

This will by default use the first column for the x-values, and the second column for the y-values.

Comment: does not work, the same error appears

Comment: @julianaperezordoñez Can you show a few lines of what your data file looks like? Edit your question to include it.

Comment: look at this: https://prnt.sc/yw5e43

Comment: @julianaperezordoñez That is a different error. In the screenshot the error is that `pgfplots` cannot find the datafile, `dicloro.txt`. The error you mention in the question is that `pgfplots` tries to interpret `14.099117,3.068e+6,` as a single number. Is `dicloro.txt` in the same folder as your `.txt` file?

Comment: yeah, this worked!! thanks

Comment: @Juliperezor, instead of/additionally to writing "thank you" in the comment, please consider [upvoting](http://tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) (by clicking on the arrows next to the score) and/or marking it as the [accepted answer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852) (by clicking on the checkmark ✓).